# VBA script #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know if anyone could tell me what's wrong with the following code

```
    Function CAPACIDADEPORT(KY As Range, KX As Range, UX)

    Dim RQUAD As Double
    
    RQUAD = WorksheetFunction.RSq(KY, KX)
    If RQUAD > 0.6 Then
        CAPACIDADEPORT = WorksheetFunction.Trend(KY, KX, UX)
        
    Else:
        CAPACIDADEPORT = WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveCell.Offset(-5))
    End If
        
   End Function
```

My goal is to create a function that return me the avarage of the last rows if the rquad value is lesser than 0.6 and the trend if the rqud is bigger or equal 0.6. But when I aplly the code it return to me a #VALUE, being that besides the UX parameters that is in general format, the other two are a range of numeric cells.

Comment: Try with Application before `WorksheetFunction`, as follows `RQUAD = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(KY.Value, KX.Value)`. `XX.Value` is alway better then `XX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the cell object.  Try KY.Value, KW.Value, UX.Value where they are referenced.

```
Function CAPACIDADEPORT(KY As Range, KX As Range, UX)

Dim RQUAD As Double

RQUAD = WorksheetFunction.RSq(KY.Value, KX.Value)
If RQUAD > 0.6 Then
    CAPACIDADEPORT = WorksheetFunction.Trend(KY.Value, KX.Value, UX.Value)
    
Else:
    CAPACIDADEPORT = WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveCell.Offset(-5))
End If
```

End Function

Comment: Thank you this help me. But after that I made some changes in my code adding a new variable and another logical test in if statmente to improve him and I got the same error.